# Laravel 5.4 + js relationship change event color if exists in pivot table

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i working on my fullcalendar. I need do something like that:
User joining to event and this event change color for a grey and event cant be editable.
I made relationship and its work good. But i dont know how in JS use checking if event exist in relation table. I do in controller some variable for a pivot table and trying in js equate event.id with event id in pivot table but its not work. I am really retarded in Js i just learning now PHP and i dont know how can i do it.
There is my code:

View:

```js
<script src="{{ asset('js/fullcalendar') }}/fullcalendar.js"></script>
 <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var base_url = '{{ url('/') }}';
    $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({
    weekends: true,
    header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek'
    },
   eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
   $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
   $('#modalBody').html(event.name);
   $('#eventUrl').attr('href','/home/zapis/'+event.id);
   $("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('HH:mm '));
   if (event.end) $("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('HH:mm '));
    else $("#endTime").html('');         
    $('#fullCalModal').modal();
    return false;
    },     
    eventLimit: true, 
    FirstDay: 1,
    contentheight : 650,
    editable : true,
    allDay : false,
    aspectRatio : 2,
    slotLabelFormat : 'HH:mm:ss',
    timeFormat : 'HH:mm',
    displayEventEnd : true,
    events: {
    url: base_url + '/api',
    error: function() {
    alert("cannot load json");
    }
    },
    //eventColor: 'white', 
   eventAfterRender: function (event, element, view,events_id) {
   if(event.id === events_id){
  element.css('backgroundcolor','#cccccc');         
       }
       else
       {
       if (event.title == "Wydzial 1") 
       {
                   element.css('background-color', '#378006');
                   }
                   else if(event.title == "Wydzial 2"){
                   element.css('background-color', '#ff0000'); 
                   }
                   else if(event.title == "Wydzial 3"){
                   element.css('background-color', '#73e600'); 
                   }
                   else{
                   element.css('background-color', '#0066ff');
                  }
            }                       
    }
          
          
    });
   });
</script>
```

Controller HomeController << its controller for calendar

```html
public function index()
{ 
    $events_id = User::with('eventsave')->get();
  return view('home',['events_id'=>$events_id]);
}
```

And HomeModel << calendar

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HomeModel extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'events'; // you may change this to your name table
 public $timestamps = true; // set true if you are using created_at and updated_at
 protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // the default is id
     
         
   public function usersave()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'save_events','events_id','users_id');
    } 
    
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me with this problem?